# Can't append value to cookie

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

My cookie is being filled with a value on the 1st pageload.
However, when I try to update it later with another value via the code below, and then refresh the page, it just shows only the initial value.
Why can't I update the cookie?

```
If Request.Cookies("lastviewed") Is Nothing Then
    Dim cookie As HttpCookie = New System.Web.HttpCookie("lastviewed", Request.RawUrl + "|" + photo + "|" + title + "|" + price)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
Else
    lastviewed = Server.UrlDecode(Request.Cookies("lastviewed").Value)
    If Not lastviewed.Contains(Request.RawUrl + "|") Then
        If lastviewed.Split(";").Length < 5 Then
            If lastviewed.Split(";").Length > 0 Then
               lastviewed = lastviewed + ";" + Request.RawUrl + "|" + photo + "|" + title + "|" + price
            Else
                lastviewed = Request.RawUrl + "|" + photo + "|" + title + "|" + price
            End If
            'this part where I want to ADD a new value to the cookie does not seem to work
            Dim cookie As New System.Web.HttpCookie("lastviewed", lastviewed)
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: **lastviewed.Contains(Request.RawUrl + "|")** , it is always true.

Comment: @AngusChung Why? This is a check if the current page is already in the cookie, if NOT, I continue and add it. It's not always true then right? And if even it was always true, at least I should see values being added to the cookie.

Comment: "it just shows only the initial value" ,  what is the initial value?

Comment: @AngusChung: on first pageview of page A, the cookie is created and set based on that URL. When I then go to page B and want to append a value to the cookie based on URL of page B, it does not do that. E.g. when I refresh page B, it just shows the cookie value that was initially set when I was on page A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because cookie cannot accept these characters：

whitespace, DQUOTE, comma, **semicolon** and backslash.

So, you can change the split character, like **@**：

```
If lastviewed.Split("@").Length < 5 Then
    If lastviewed.Split("@").Length > 0 Then
        lastviewed = lastviewed + "@" + Request.RawUrl + "|" + photo + "|" + Title + "|" + price
```

try it again.

Comment: Doing that always executes this line `lastviewed = Request.RawUrl + "|" + photo + "|" + title + "|" + price` so nothing is appended anymore.

Comment: What you want to append??

Comment: This line builds the new value to be set for the cookie (when I say append, I mean that this value can replace the existing cookie): `lastviewed = lastviewed + ";" + Request.RawUrl + "|" + photo + "|" + title + "|" + price`